# Should a view model handle onClick?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

Given: "a ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context" should I not handle onClick listeners in the view model?

Right now, I am binding a view's onClickListener to a method within my ViewModel which changes the value of a MutableLiveData. The implementation works fine but I am wondering if this is a generally poor implementation architecturally - and why?

Comment: You are not holding onto a view, lifecycle, or any class just by being an event listener. You are *passed* a view to your `OnClickListener` (or equivalent lambda expression). So long as you do not then hold onto that view in a field or property, you are not at risk of having a memory leak.

Comment: Ok that makes sense